# Using nth child (for every 3 + 1)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to style a series of divs, depending on their position. I want them to be styled, like so:

```
<div class="col33"></div> <!--  red -->
<div class="col33"></div>
<div class="col33"></div> <!--  orange -->

<div class="col33"></div> <!--  red -->
<div class="col33"></div>
<div class="col33"></div> <!--  orange -->

<div class="col33"></div> <!--  red -->
<div class="col33"></div>
<div class="col33"></div> <!--  orange -->
```

But I can only seem to get every third child:

```
.col33:nth-child(3n) {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UAj6h/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another rule for `3n+1` div

```
.col33:nth-child(3n) {
    background-color: orange;
}
.col33:nth-child(3n+1) {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UAj6h/4/

As a side note, you may avoid to use redundant `.col33` class, in order to reduce markup size
and you may target those div with `.parent-div > div`

Answer (score 1):

Just add `.col33:nth-child(3n-2)` or `.col33:nth-child(3n+1)` for your red divs.

```
.col33:nth-child(3n-2) {
    background: #ff4136;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/t6rfm/)

Comment: Do 3n-2 and 3n+1 do exactly the same? 3n+1 seems to be easier to understand for me.

Comment: 3n-2 applies to: -2, 1, 4, etc. 3n+1 affects 1, 4, etc. Both do the same as -2 doesn't exist.